# How extracting meaning of sentences for sentiment analysis using NLP

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

"I had safe journey" ,assume this is a feedback for a driver ,provided by a  passenger. I need to extract theses information from this sentence..

```
"I had safe journey" -> 
 SUBJECT= "driving"
 SENTIMENT= "positive"
```

I tried with NLP Extracting Information from Text method. But I don't know how recognized Entities from these kind of sentences.How am I supposed to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To categorize entities of a sentence or a sentence as a whole, you first need to have defined set of classes/categories/groups.

for eg: To categorize ***journey*** to ***travelling/driving***, you should train your system/algorithm to ***identify*** specific pattern of sentences which will fall under the category of ***driving/journey***.

This ***training*** involves concepts of ***machine learning***, ***`Text Categorization`*** is what you should be searching for.

[Here](http://www.quora.com/Natural-Language-Processing/What-is-the-best-approach-for-text-categorization) is a reference (to just give you an idea) and you can find many more over the web.

Good Luck!

Note: Below are some links from Coursera which offers a course on NLP
[Link 1](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp)
[Link 2](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlangp)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Now I have a guide for solve my problem